# Return value based on count from SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Server Stored Procedure which validates a password.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spValidatePassword]
@UserId uniqueidentifier,
@Password NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PasswordHash NVARCHAR(255) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', (SELECT @Password + CAST((SELECT p.PasswordSalt FROM Passwords p WHERE p.UserId =     @UserId) AS NVARCHAR(255))))

SELECT COUNT(*)
from Passwords
WHERE UserId = @UserId
AND [Password] = @PasswordHash


--return 1 if valid password
--return 0 if not valid

END
```

How can I return 1 from the stored procedure if the count is greater than zero, and zero otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spValidatePassword]
@UserId uniqueidentifier,
@Password NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PasswordHash NVARCHAR(255) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', (SELECT @Password + CAST((SELECT p.PasswordSalt FROM Passwords p WHERE p.UserId =     @UserId) AS NVARCHAR(255))))

SELECT 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         from Passwords
         WHERE UserId = @UserId
         AND [Password] = @PasswordHash
         )
 THEN 1 
 ELSE 0
 END


--return 1 if valid password
--return 0 if not valid

END
```

But consider using some other authentication model like OAuth or Office 365 logins rather than reinventing the wheel

Comment: Thanks Nick. The authentication is using OWIN but it is against a legacy database.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query, will return `1` if there is a result, else `0`

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Passwords
WHERE UserId = @UserId
AND [Password] = @PasswordHash
```

Comment: and if there are 10 matching rows this select returns 10 rows of 1's

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, No, Never, u can try COUNT in a simple table with a WHERE clause.

Comment: Oh! Interesting I never knew that. I take it back.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF    (SELECT COUNT(UserId) from Passwords WHERE UserId = @UserId  AND [Password] = @PasswordHash) > 0
begin
    return 1;
End
ELse
begin
   return 0;
end
```

this query will return the required result

Comment: No. If there are 3 matching records this will return 3. The result is no different to `COUNT(*)`

Comment: check modified answer

Comment: OK so now this one returns data using `RETURN` rather than `SELECT`

Comment: you can use select 1 in place of return 1

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         from Passwords
         WHERE UserId = @UserId
         AND [Password] = @PasswordHash
         )
RETURN 1;
ELSE
RETURN 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use OUTPUT Type stored procedure to get a scalar (in your case either 1 or 0) result as:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spValidatePassword]
@UserId uniqueidentifier,
@Password NVARCHAR(255),
@result TINYINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @PasswordHash NVARCHAR(255) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', (SELECT @Password + CAST((SELECT p.PasswordSalt FROM Passwords p WHERE p.UserId =     @UserId) AS NVARCHAR(255))))

SELECT @result = COUNT(*)
from Passwords
WHERE UserId = @UserId
AND [Password] = @PasswordHash

END
```

You can execute this proc as:

```
DECLARE @output TINYINT

EXEC [dbo].[spValidatePassword]  @UserId= 'any user id',@Password = 'any password',@result = @output OUTPUT

PRINT @output
```